# New PI 2 B+ unusably slow, CPU and RAM not being used?

Tags: raspbian, performance, memory, cpu, pi-2

Just setup a new R Pi 2B+, using raspbian on a 16gb sd card, ethernet, USB mouse/keyboard and HDMI out.

Finding it extremely slow - the UI is reasonably responsive however installing monodevelop took about two hours. CPU and ram stay around 5% with peak about 30%. I was able to start a C# GUI project in monodevelop and run it without any issues which was nice.

SD card is getting a lot of access when I would expect it to be using far more ram, but its also slow when not accessing SD.

Browser is almost unusable (with one OR many tabs, default or Iceweasel), but cpu/ram are empty. Process memory usage is higher than the total used in ram, which is almost empty.

Would like to know if theres a better performance/task monitor app which can show all 4 cores, set affinity, memory and swap usage etc..?

Ive searched other questions about slowness but could not see any that are related to low cpu usage and empty ram.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `top` for monitoring CPU / memory usage.

Comment: You don't say what you are comparing the speeds against.

Comment: What is your network connection like.

Comment: Network is good, it was quite fast downloading the packages for monodevelop, just installing took ages.

Ive not used a Pi before but I assume it should be as fast as an equally or lesser specced old phone, for example a ZTE Blade.

Comment: i dont know if `top` shows all cores, but `htop` does.

Comment: Have a look through `/var/log/syslog` and/or at `dmesg` output when something is obviously wrong (it's slow, but should not be as sluggish as you describe); it may be due to an I/O issue.

Comment: I did try dmesg, it shows the boot info but nothing obviously wrong other than a couple of warnings during boot.

Ive tryed youtube in both browsers. It renders about 1 FPS..

Comment: As per earlier comments I'd ignore whatever little CPU widget [LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) (Raspian's default DE) might supply in favour of `top` or `htop`.  This will also help to isolate what's going on with specific processes.

Comment: If you're experienced enough, you could try to move the root filesystem onto a USB drive. MicroSD cards are often (at least to my experience) quite slow which may affect the perceived operating speed of raspbian.

Comment: @user236012 Unless the OP is grotesquely exaggerating, it shouldn't be like this regardless.  If your car is not running properly, it may still go faster on a paved highway but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Im getting a message on boot that does not show up in logs.

Comment: '[warn] kernel lacks cgroups or memory controller not available, not starting cgroups.'

Seems unrelated?
Using the Pi tonight, its obvious it is using the SD card excessivley. Top is showing 500mg free, while doing anything, for example a new tab, or even just one tab going to google, takes 30 seconds. An old phone can do it in 2 seconds.

Speaking of which, how do I get the full fat version of firefox on here, rather than Iceweasel? I do not like having to constantly request the desktop version of a site.

Comment: @Kram , that's a different question. However check out [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) link. Though I don't think the full version of Firefox is supported for the Pi (don't quote me on this though).

Comment: Put it in a non transparent box(ie dark place out of light). Try a different SD card. Samsung EVO (orange ones are very decent!) If it continues... it may be faulty. RMA and replace. The browser should run really slick on the Pi2. Make sure you have 256mb GPU atleast also

Comment: I also am experiencing this issue (e.g. launching Chromium takes ~15 seconds). I seem to satisfy the specs for all the "solutions" suggested so far, but they don't resolve my issue. (1) My file system is already "expanded" via `sudo raspi-config`. (2) My SD card is UHS (Ultra High Speed) class 1 which is higher than HS class 10. (3) My network connection speed is great. (4) Using `top` the `chromium-browse` process consumes on average 45% CPU and 20% Memory. (5) My power source is plugged into a wall socket (5v 2000mA). Any other insights?

Comment: Update to #5 of my previous response: I tried with a 2.5A power source (compared to the 2A one that I had) with no change in performance. The search continues...

Answer (score 2):

A totally obvious solution I'm afraid, have you expanded the file system? You can do this on Raspbian by running

```
sudo raspi-config
```

As I said, it's fairly obvious but easily overlooked and would give you exactly the issue you're facing

Comment: This should normally go into a comment... but seeing that I believe you need 15 rep to post a comment it's alright. Remember next time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the sd-card is of a low class, that would fit together with slow installations with good internet connection and good processor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two highly likely scenario's here:

1) The SD card isn't fast enough

> Buy a better one, class 10 with good read/write speeds

2) your power supply isn't up to the task

> Get a good quality (preferably not to long) cable with a 5V 2A adapter.